# Programmers Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion, contest

Did you know Programmer SE's birthday is coming up on **December 16th**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: We've set up [a brainstorming chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2050/programmer-contest-conspiracy-room)...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Would you mind joining the comment chat in the answer below?

Comment: @Jae: No I will NOT join your splinter group! Herecy! :P (I'll join in if I have something useful to say, don't worry I'm not shy)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [Programmer Contest Conspiracy Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2050/programmer-contest-conspiracy-room), I think we have found a celebration activity. It is a "Concept a Week" event, based on that of [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) (I am not sure if it is going on still, though).

Basically, each week there will be a new "concept". If you ask a question about, or having to do with this concept, there is an incentive (I'm not sure what that will be, leave a comment if you have an idea).

This will help the Programmers.SE information grow in categories that are needed, and it's a fun event!

So far we have this figured out:

- The questions must abide by the rules stated in the FAQ to get an incentive.
- The incentive will not be big. It will be either your name in a drawing or a virtual prize having to do with SE.
- You may NOT get an incentive if the question was already asked.
- If your question is part of the contest, you will include something like *[contest]* in your title. If not, and your question has to do with the current topic, no incentive will be earned.
- Bounties on previous questions on the topic do NOT count. Neither do edits to a previously written question.

There is a chat room for working out details that [can be found here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2116/concept-of-the-week-contest-details)

Comment: Details can be worked out here as far as I know. Unlike Main, Meta supports discussions.

Comment: @WorldEngineer: Then feel free to work it out here. Either way really...

Comment: @WorldEngineer : So do you have any ideas on what we can do incentive wise? Maybe an xp boost or a special badge (or both:-)

Comment: SE Swag (T-shirts etc.) are the usual incentives.

Comment: @ChrisF: But do we want to be usual?

Comment: @ChrisF: The users of Programmers.SE aren't exactly usual.

Comment: Winner gets three free passes to ask "What is your favorite <noun> (as a programmer)?" or "Why are programmers <adjective>?" questions! *ducks*

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Honestly, that's a great idea. The question is how do you _win_ this contest?

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Could be it be question of the week question with most _votes_? Or... something else?

Comment: @Jae I was being facetious: it'll be a cold day in hell before we'd allow anything of the sort.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: LOL. Sorry... I thought you lost it there! But the questions still stand- "How do you win?" and "What will you win?".

Comment: @WorldEngineer: Do you have an idea?

Comment: Jae take a look at the latest [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/hot-topics-a-contest-formula-that-works/) for inspiration - the SE people seem to like the idea.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Thanks! It seems they are going towards a drawing instead of a more competitive competition. As far as I know, nobody has bluntly stated that they want a drawing nor any other choice. Right now, I am not really geared towards a drawing/raffle, but it's up to the community. Unfortunately, not to may users are getting in on the conversation...

Comment: @MarkTrapp: In all seriousness, how if we answer those two questions, then this can get started. Can we set up a quick poll? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Jae I've pinged SE to see what their thoughts are on an incentive, but it's important to be realistic: we can't change the rep formula, bend the quality guidelines, or grant badges for winning a weekly contest (or any contest, for that matter). Think more like swag or product giveaways or other things that don't compromise the integrity of the SE Q&A formula.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: I understand quality guidelines and badges, but why not rep? Would it be difficult to provide the user with rep/xp? If it is I'm sorry if this is annoying. But if not, I don't see why not...

Comment: @Jae Reputation [is a measure of how much the community trusts your post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) with one single formula across the entire network. A post isn't suddenly more trustworthy because the person who wrote won a contest at one point in the past.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: OK... makes sense. Sorry about that. But a friend recommended an idea: Free commercial programming tool i.e. Perl Dev Pack but something on a cheaper scale.

Comment: @Jae Something like that sounds like it could definitely work.

Comment: Literature SE does a cheap (ish) book as a reward for posting well during their "author of the week" thing. I think a cheap dev tool or book (are there any cheap books? :)) could work here.

Comment: Agreed, @AnnaLear. The reasoning behind a small prize and a random raffle/drawing (provided the question is tagged appropriately and has a positive score) is so people aren't motivated enough to break the integrity of the system but rather gently reminded to ask those questions here and maybe get a gift.

Comment: @AnnaLear: So should we base whether or not they get a book or dev tools on quality of the question. For example very high quality questions get a dev kit while high quality questions get a book? Or something better?

Comment: @Jae Other sites are basically doing random drawings for the prize and each question about the topic gets the poster one entry into the draw. I think we can certainly place some restrictions on the questions (for example, closed questions don't count), but beyond that... judging quality would be very difficult and very subjective. I think we can only go as far as to say that the question has to have a strictly positive score and then provide the same prize price point (e.g. $50) for all winners.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Well the community can always deside on quality. For example, we get the top 5 questions that were entered in the contest (based on upvotes) and let the community vote each week on which ones shall get the prize. I don't think it should be a raffle since some questions may be more deserving (in the eyes of the community) than others...

Comment: @Jae The number of upvotes on a question is an indicator of popularity, not quality. The key to this, in my opinion, is to make the draw random and allow every participant a chance to win. Making this a complex process with quality judging and extra votes doesn't guarantee that the best questions will get rewarded nor is it going to be particularly fun to run due to the administrative overhead.

Comment: @AnnaLear: But a random question isn't exactly fair to somebody with a quality question. Maybe we should let the moderators decide who's best. Or a group of hand-picked judges. But not random raffle...

Comment: @Jae I can't speak for other moderators, but I know that I certainly don't want to spend more time judging questions. :) The contest prize is meant to just be an incentive. The idea is to encourage people to post questions in a fun and welcoming environment, not to create an atmosphere of competition. I believe a formal judging process would do the latter, so I strongly oppose any contest system that requires us (as a community) to determine the quality of a question beyond the basic ruling out of closed or negatively scored questions.

Comment: @AnnaLear: [This SuperUser blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) is a good example of my idea, but not all of it. Look down to the categories you can win in. How do you win most of the prizes? There is a Moderator Judge Panel. Now, I'm not going to put any work on you, Mark, Chris, or Josh if you don't want more :). But we can appoint a judging panel. If there is no competition Question X may be the most amazing question on the site, while the winner Question Y, is not so much. I believe that would just be the fair way to run this contest...

Comment: @Jae Keep in mind that SU did that once for their birthday. If I'm not mistaken, you're proposing a weekly contest here, which certainly would increase the workload.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ok... I give. We'll go with the drawing. But, to make it a more difficult for bad questions to be eligible, there must be some pretty high standards set. Deal? ;-)

Comment: @MarkTrapp: What do you think?

Comment: @Jae I agree with Anna and Seth: we've spoken with the SU mods about their contests and other sites that have attempted to do the same thing, and it winds up being a lot of work for questionable benefit. However, one thing Gaming.SE did over the holidays was to [rassle up a bounty posse to reward exemplary posts after the fact](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3506/3389): that's something to consider doing on a periodic basis or in addition to a "traditional" contest/giveaway.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: So... is that it? I can't seem to think of anything else that we need to think of. Of course, I don't remember much... Are we okay? Can we get this started?

Comment: @AnnaLear: So... overall, what do you think. Can we make this happen?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: What do you think? Anything we can fix?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ummm.... hello?

Comment: @Jae Ack, sorry. Things've been a bit crazy. I'll ping the other mods and see where we're at.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks! Sorry if I've been a bit annoying...

Comment: @Jae No worries. I appreciate your enthusiasm. :) We'll probably have to summarize what we've talked about here and answer a few remaining questions. Then us moderators will work with SE-the-company to see if we can get something going. I'll try to get a summary up this weekend.

Comment: OK. If you need any help, feel free to ask. And don't forget about me ;-)

Comment: @AnnaLear: Was wondering if you have a summary... if so, would you mind presenting it? If not... just tel me what you need and I'll get it done.

Comment: @Jae Sorry, the weekend got busy. :) Summary will go up tonight.

Comment: @AnnaLear: No problem. Hoping this goes up soon. Will it be posted as an answer?

Comment: @Jae Posted as a new question [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/belated-birthday-celebration-proposal).

Comment: @AnnaLear: It seems the one answer you got (as of this comment) doesn't agree with us too much. Read the answer if you haven't already and see if you agree. Get back to me ASAP.

Comment: @Jae I saw it. We can continue working things out there. It just proves that bringing the discussion out of this comment thread was a good idea. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: It seems there are mixed feelings about whether or not the community wants this idea or a SU style idea...

Comment: @AnnaLear: I've talked to ZaphodBeeblebrox. He, basically, said talk to you, and see what we can do to get an SU like contest going instead of a weekly thing, which I don't mind doing at all. On a workload stand-point, Zaphod and I both said we are willing to judge and withdraw from the contest if needed. But since the major workload shall fall on the moderators, I'd say you should make sure they agree, and that YOU agree. Whether you like this idea or not, please ping me ASAP with an answer.

Comment: @Jae This discussion has to continue on the other post. It's getting lost here and nobody else can follow it. Feel free to post an answer there to summarize what you and Zaphod talked about. There has to be community consensus here before we proceed with anything.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Do you want to keep this going? It seems this idea went static...

Comment: @AnnaLear Small correction here, I suggested Jae should contact you via chat, but only to discuss his own concerns further, not push for the one contest or the other. More importantly, my position is that I don't see the community caring enough, both discussions are stale. I don't care which one we do, what I care about is for more people to get involved.

Comment: @Jae Not really until there is clear community consensus. And please read again the comment where I suggested you speak with Anna, I wasn't advocating for any type of event. I don't want an event that only represents what a handful of us thinks. Post competing meta answers, even if only to serve as down vote fodder...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Honestly, before we do do anything, we need to get others to get somewhat interested. The question is how?

Comment: @Jae That's the million dollar question. I have no idea :(

Comment: @YannisRizos: Is there any way we can get an ad? Like, instead of promoting a proposed site on Area51 we put up an ad about this, and have it link to either the summary meta question or this one...

Comment: @Jae I don't know. And when I don't know, [I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119817/how-can-we-get-people-to-participate-on-meta) :)