# Structured Tag Cleanup: [career]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, posse, stci

> **Related:**
>
> [Request for comment: structured tag cleanups](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/request-for-comment-structured-tag-cleanups)
>
> [Structured Tag Cleanup — Call for proposals #1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/structured-tag-cleanup-call-for-proposals-1)

Welcome to the first structured tag cleanup! Based on the voting in the [call for proposals](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/structured-tag-cleanup-call-for-proposals-1), the first round goes to the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag, with 567 current questions.

As a means to contain the disaster, the tag has been renamed to [stci-c​areer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-career), which should prevent people from adding any more questions to it.

#### Ground rules

The goal of this cleanup is to systematically clean up the career tag without causing disruption to the rest of the site.  Your job, should you choose to accept it, is:

- Review the [deletion candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3172/8) below and see if there's a way to save any of the questions before they go gently into that good night through [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits). At the end of the clean up period, any questions not sufficiently improved will be deleted.
- Review the [merge candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3173/8) to see if can be merged into one question. If they shouldn't be, revise the questions to demonstrate how it's not in any way like the question it's been duplicated to.
- Review the [closure candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3174/8) list to see if you agree with what others have identified as being out of the site's scope. If you agree, vote to close. If you don't agree, use [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) to address the problems the question has and bring it back into scope.
- Review the currently open questions and see which ones do not fit our site scope. Vote to close them and add them to the closure candidates list.
- Improve the leftover questions by copyediting, fixing spelling, flow, adding clearer titles, etc. while replacing the `stci-c​areer` tag with something more meaningful:

  [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) for questions about taking steps to improve one's programming career and *requires* the unique insights of a programmer
  [interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview) for questions about interviewing for a software development position
  [hiring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring) for questions about hiring programmers and other software developers
  [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market) for questions about the prospects or what one needs to do to get a specific job in software development
  [job-title](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-title) for questions about what a specific type of software development job entails
  [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) for questions about managing the scope and requirements of a specific project
  [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) for questions about working within a software development team

  ...and other, more specific tags as needed.
- Finally, and this is perhaps the most important of all the rules: **do not just remove the stci-c​areer tag without improving the question.** If all our tag problems were solved by retagging, we would've done so months ago. Every time you retag without improving a question, I silently judge you:

  ### ಠ_ಠ

#### End date

This round of cleanups will end on **Wednesday, March 7th at 04:00 UTC.** At that time, all the default actions will be done: deletions, merges, closures, and such. If the `stci-c​areer` tag is not empty by then, it'll be renamed back to [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and be saved for later rounds of cleanups.

Good luck, and godspeed!

Comment: Just a few helpful links: The [open questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-career%5D+closed%3A0), the [closed questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-career%5D+closed%3A1), the [unanswered questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-career%5D+answers%3A0), the [questions without accepted answers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-career%5D+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A0), and [the community wiki questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-career%5D+wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: How are you planning to determine if a question stays open or not? I hope you are not relying on re-open votes, because I noticed the re-open count on [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/23075/1130) decreasing and apparently re-open votes expire after a few days

Answer (score 4):

#### Merge candidates

Please review these questions closed as duplicates to see if they can be merged. If they shouldn't be merged, please use [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) to clarify why the questions aren't duplicates of each other and vote to reopen.

- [Move on and look elsewhere, or confront the boss?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86502/move-on-and-look-elsewhere-or-confront-the-boss) →
  [When do you know it's time to move on from your current job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/when-do-you-know-its-time-to-move-on-from-your-current-job)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/will-programmers-be-around-in-a-few-years →
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9539/what-trends-do-you-see-for-your-profession-in-30-years
- [Does being a jack-of-all-trades hurt your career?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81160/does-being-a-jack-of-all-trades-hurt-your-career) →
  [Is it better to specialize in a single field I like, or expand into other fields to broaden my horizons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20653/is-it-better-to-specialize-in-a-single-field-i-like-or-expand-into-other-fields)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361/ive-graduated-with-a-computer-science-degree-but-i-dont-feel-like-im-even-clo →
  [I'm graduating with a Computer Science degree but I don't feel like I know how to program](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43528/im-graduating-with-a-computer-science-degree-but-i-dont-feel-like-i-know-how-t)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15857/did-microsoft-kill-silverlight →
  [Does Silverlight have a future?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28078/does-silverlight-have-a-future)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20723/how-do-i-get-better-at-acing-technical-interviews →
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93384/how-can-i-really-wow-an-employer-at-an-interview
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41720/which-order-would-you-teach-programming-languages-in-when-teaching-a-newbie →
  [Ideal programming language learning sequence?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/ideal-programming-language-learning-sequence)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61678/can-a-developer-move-into-a-fast-paced-career-later-in-life →
  [How old is "too old"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-old-is-too-old)

Answer (score 3):

#### Deletion candidates

Please review these questions to see which can be saved through [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) and reopened. If no improvement would make them on topic, vote to delete if you have the reputation.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18120/what-is-the-good-bad-decision-you-made-in-your-mid-20s-about-your-career
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88798/am-i-an-idealist
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63657/i-made-a-mistake-accepting-this-job
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36007/which-are-the-best-investments-you-have-done-for-your-career-as-programmer
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18502/who-wants-to-keep-developing
- [What is the most productive way to handle development-related failures?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23075/what-is-the-coolest-way-to-handle-a-failure)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39992/are-there-too-many-qualified-software-development-engineers-chasing-too-few-jobs
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11425/burned-out-on-programming-and-given-up
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14827/typical-hours-week-for-programmers
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20866/the-job-is-stressing-me-out-and-i-am-unable-to-get-enough-sleep-at-night
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69500/dont-make-me-write-bad-code-is-that-all-programmers-really-want
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49105/how-do-you-apply-to-a-company-way-out-of-your-league
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21782/stagnating-in-programming
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46514/what-to-do-when-youre-the-interviewer-and-you-dont-like-your-job
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22714/what-are-the-telltale-signs-that-the-code-youre-writing-is-already-obsolete
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/how-do-you-motivate-yourself-to-program-when-youd-really-rather-be-doing-somet
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63592/how-do-senior-developers-keep-up-to-learning-as-much-as-a-junior
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53168/what-are-some-good-performance-goals-for-a-software-engineer
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/how-do-you-manage-your-resume-cv
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16222/how-to-remain-calm-in-all-situations
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/what-are-the-top-motivators-for-a-programmer

Comment: Would you consider leaving some of these questions Closed but not Deleted so we can write blog posts based on the content, and then delete them after the post goes up?

Comment: @Rachel Please don't make irrelevant edits to the answers here.  To answer your question, no, closed questions that won't be salvaged will be deleted. You will be able to still see the questions after they are deleted, since you are a 10K+ user, so there isn't actually any reason for special treatment.

Comment: @YannisRizos I was trying to mark the questions that I wanted to expand into blog posts. I do not plan on writing much for our blog, and some of our writers do not have the 10k rep required to view deleted posts. I was not trying to keep the questions open - I merely wanted to mark them so I could start blog topics on them, and once the post has been written, we'd flag the question for deletion.

Comment: @Rachel We're not deleting these immediately: there's two weeks available to say goodbyes and save the content off-site if someone wants it for the future. [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) is good for that purpose.

Comment: @Rachel I know... Ask a different Meta question, we can assemble a list of other questions as well, not just career (you can easily copy paste your picks from the above list from the revision history). We'll still delete them, if they are part of the cleanup effort, but I (and you) could easily move them off site if there's enough interest to write blog posts about them.

Comment: @Rachel It's going to be much easier to let the community respond if you create a question for each of these questions you're trying to save.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Good idea, I'll create a few questions and delete my comments

Answer (score 3):

#### Closure candidates

Add any question you find while combing [the [stci-career] tag](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3206/25936) that does not meet the site's scope and fell through the cracks. Review any existing question to see if it does need to be closed or can be saved by a [heroic edit](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits).

1. [How can I program effectively during an Internet outage?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84908/how-can-i-program-effectively-during-an-internet-outage)
2. [Overwhelmed at Internship](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84822/overwhelmed-at-internship)
3. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84484/considering-career-change-to-patent-agent-patent-engineer
4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82920/looking-for-unpaid-interns-2-am-i-crazy
5. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82055/non-solicitation-clause-in-my-offer-letter-prospective-employer-says-this-is-n
6. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/1st-bachelors-degree-or-2-1-masters-degree
7. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81644/internships-between-sophomore-and-junior-years
8. [Quitting a small start-up where you are a primary developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79487/quitting-a-small-start-up-where-you-are-a-primary-developer)
9. [How to network effectively to get a job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77886/how-to-network-effectively-to-get-a-job)
10. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77014/doing-a-passive-job-search-while-employed-dealing-with-the-barrage-of-messages
11. [Most effective way to increase programmer salary besides just doing your job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76254/most-effective-way-to-increase-programmer-salary-besides-just-doing-your-job)
12. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74954/what-does-remote-position-with-possibility-of-re-locating-mean
13. [Good questions to ask the CEO and CTO of a start-up during an interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74583/good-questions-to-ask-the-ceo-and-cto-of-a-start-up-during-an-interview)
14. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73838/job-in-other-country-relocation-package
15. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72874/what-is-better-mba-vs-mis-right-after-grad-or-gap
16. [So they're trying to pull me into management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72001/so-theyre-trying-to-pull-me-into-management)
17. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71925/i-want-to-have-a-career-not-a-job
18. [Employee vs Contractor mentality and career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66794/employee-vs-contractor-mentality-and-career)
19. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64412/how-to-handle-a-workaholic-supervisor-who-is-your-good-friend
20. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64383/i-quit-my-job-but-took-back-my-resignation-during-the-notice-period-did-i-mad
21. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62999/what-benefits-should-an-intern-look-for-aside-from-pay
22. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62399/should-i-stay-or-should-i-go
23. [Moving from a small to a large company](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60324/moving-from-a-small-to-a-large-company)
24. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58250/what-percentage-should-a-consulting-company-take-off-the-top-of-your-pay
25. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/should-i-be-an-algorithm-developer-or-java-web-frameworks-type-developer
26. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84468/what-defines-a-skill-technology
27. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83786/career-help-for-an-experienced-professional
28. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81555/what-should-i-learn-if-im-thinking-of-going-into-networking
29. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/specialized-course-in-web-programming-or-generalized-course-in-computer-science
30. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45715/educational-qualification-of-a-programmer
31. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44028/future-direction-for-a-developer-who-is-expert-in-latest-software-technologies
32. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43739/experienced-keeping-up-with-the-times-or-new-to-the-game-only-using-the-newe
33. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37968/should-i-stay-in-my-degree-or-take-an-opportunity-for-management-experience
34. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33488/entity-type-for-freelance-programmer
35. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24277/web-programming-vs-oracle-courses
36. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/project-dotnetnuke-module-selling-website-problem-staying-motivated
37. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86432/web-security-course
38. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86412/transition-from-maintenance-programming-to-design
39. [Matching my skills with Java and Web Programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85995/matching-my-skills-with-java-and-web-programming)
40. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82150/career-switch-from-high-level-to-kernel-programming
41. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75334/how-much-does-the-calibre-of-a-masters-program-matter-to-an-employer
42. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74016/will-cfa-add-any-value-to-a-programmer
43. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73763/how-to-pick-which-mcpd-certification-is-appropriate
44. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/php-interview-test-any-advice
45. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72122/integration-projects-consulting-and-biztalk-good-or-bad-for-career
46. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70432/seeking-advice-for-a-student
47. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69992/web-to-sql-development
48. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68906/graduate-versus-undergraduate-for-career-change
49. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68818/a-job-in-big-company-like-ibm-microsoft-vs-own-small-1-2-people-software-compan
50. [How do you handle the problem of abstraction when you learn a techonology / language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66886/how-do-you-handle-the-problem-of-abstraction-when-you-learn-a-techonology-lang)
51. [How to conduct a good tech workshop](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62816/how-to-conduct-a-good-tech-workshop)
52. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62560/c-pigeonholing
53. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61349/interview-recruiter-to-ask-series-of-technical-questions
54. [Case studies for successful service (project) based software development businesses without constant overtime from its employees](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68370/case-studies-for-successful-service-project-based-businesses-without-constant)
55. [Independent projects as a student to show off abilities](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85946/independent-projects-as-a-student-to-show-off-abilities)
56. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/getting-started-on-large-projects
57. [Dealing with engineers that frequently leave their jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43409/dealing-with-engineers-that-frequently-leave-their-jobs)
58. [How to move ahead in Project/Product Management after 3 yrs of Programming Experience?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39939/how-to-move-ahead-in-project-product-management-after-3-yrs-of-programming-exper)
59. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21970/the-donts-of-it-project-management
60. [How can I quickly weed out "copy & paste" coders?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20178/how-can-i-quickly-weed-out-copy-paste-coders)
61. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18578/pmp-certificate-how-did-you-achieve-it-how-was-the-preparation
62. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/from-programmer-to-programmers-coach
63. [About the book "Peopleware - Productive Projects and Teams"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/about-the-book-peopleware-productive-projects-and-teams)
64. [What roles do people take after scrum master/technical lead?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50168/what-roles-do-people-take-after-scrum-master-technical-lead)
65. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39888/job-title-inflation-and-fluffing
66. [System Analyst vs Computer Programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38382/system-analyst-vs-computer-programmer)
67. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27317/is-there-a-future-for-full-time-software-configuration-managers-engineers
68. [Why I'm not selected in an interview?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21412/why-im-not-selected-in-an-interview)
69. [How to deal with Interviews where HR is missing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/how-to-deal-with-interviews-where-hr-is-missing)
70. [How you prepared for your .NET interview?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-you-prepared-for-your-net-interview)
71. [When being a technical genius is not enough to be a successful developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20564/when-being-a-technical-genius-is-not-enough-to-be-a-successful-developer)
72. [What can I do when the interviewer doesn't know the answer to his/her own question?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35038/what-can-i-do-when-the-interviewer-doesnt-know-the-answer-to-his-her-own-questi)
73. [Why are SW engineering interviews disproportionately difficult (vs. research interviews)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47778/why-are-sw-engineering-interviews-disproportionately-difficult-vs-research-int)
74. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/how-do-you-know-a-company-is-worth-working-at-or-not
75. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57953/should-i-include-c-private-tutoring-experience-on-my-cv-resume
76. [I'm scared for my technical phone interview for an internship!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58667/im-scared-for-my-technical-phone-interview-for-an-internship)
77. [Interview question: which is the time period estimated by you to learn Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62217/interview-question-which-is-the-time-period-estimated-by-you-to-learn-java)
78. [Do you count a Masters in CS as a negative?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47176/do-you-count-a-masters-in-cs-as-a-negative)
79. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/career-advice-for-self-taught-programmers
80. [career advice for PhD scientist seeking to program?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48859/career-advice-for-phd-scientist-seeking-to-program)
81. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58576/where-is-a-good-place-to-get-career-advice-in-the-uk
82. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55493/delphi-to-java-change-career-advice
83. [Career advice: PhD in theory of programming languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46582/career-advice-phd-in-theory-of-programming-languages)
84. [Career advice: stay with PHP or start a new career in something else ( .Net?)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/career-advice-stay-with-php-or-start-a-new-career-in-something-else-net)
85. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75963/career-in-robotics
86. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26003/career-advice-should-i-relearn-xhtml-and-css-for-my-career
87. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/career-advice-needed-startups-clients-making-moves-the-whole-ball-of-wax
88. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/career-advice-what-can-i-do-to-ensure-i-am-able-to-provide-for-my-family-when-i
89. [Moving your career to another programming language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61764/moving-your-career-to-another-programming-language)
90. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20677/need-some-advice-for-next-big-thing-and-career-advancement
91. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80296/a-developer-as-it-manager-advice
92. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67170/should-i-join-non-software-company-or-software-company
93. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49018/cs-concentrations-and-career-paths
94. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48911/viable-part-time-career-in-it-programming
95. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38165/how-often-have-you-switched-stacks-in-your-career-has-it-hurt-your-career-progr
96. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40818/career-in-game-development
97. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61064/career-prospects-in-research
98. [Switching to a career in Machine Learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54423/switching-to-a-career-in-machine-learning)
99. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38799/does-taking-a-series-of-contracts-hurt-your-career
100. [Am I going to damage my career if I switched to a completely different route?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37802/am-i-going-to-damage-my-career-if-i-switched-to-a-completely-different-route)
101. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56552/what-should-i-look-into-to-find-a-career-path
102. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40642/advice-for-transitioning-into-a-java-developer-position-from-doing-other-types-o
103. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31536/will-taking-two-years-off-for-school-in-a-related-field-destroy-a-mid-level-deve
104. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74724/how-long-can-you-be-out-of-the-ms-market-before-it-affects-your-career
105. [I've been programming in one language for many years. Is this career suicide?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80573/ive-been-programming-in-one-language-for-many-years-is-this-career-suicide)
106. [Career path for software QA / Test engineer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81439/career-path-for-software-qa-test-engineer)
107. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8340/need-advice-on-making-the-transition-from-a-net-development-shop-to-a-java-shop
108. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48359/want-to-transform-my-career-to-oracle-financial
109. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51165/leaving-the-field-of-programming-what-are-the-options
110. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38431/what-can-i-do-to-advance-my-knowledge-as-a-supplement-to-a-software-engineering
111. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39067/if-you-switched-your-major-career-to-go-into-programming-how-do-you-deal-with-l
112. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/professional-developers-may-i-join-you
113. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50370/so-my-employer-wants-me-to-do-less-programming-and-focus-on-it-support
114. [Career guidance books for programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/career-guidance-books-for-programmers)
115. [Work advancement titles](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39353/work-advancement-titles)
116. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/advice-for-how-to-handle-company-pride
117. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37192/what-is-the-path-to-become-a-manager-cio-cto
118. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55695/gaining-experience-in-systems-programming
119. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40054/have-you-worked-at-a-place-which-did-not-mandate-annual-employee-evaluations-or
120. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/senior-software-developer
121. [If you take a year or two out from being a developer, is it really that hard to get back into it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27091/if-you-take-a-year-or-two-out-from-being-a-developer-is-it-really-that-hard-to)
122. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39940/asked-to-put-in-extra-hours
123. [I've stopped coding for fun, is this a bad sign?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/ive-stopped-coding-for-fun-is-this-a-bad-sign)
124. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22983/is-it-easy-for-a-developer-to-become-a-system-business-analysts
125. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/how-to-go-about-working-as-a-contract-consultant-remotely
126. [How could your company's learning/development department best serve you?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24538/how-could-your-companys-learning-development-department-best-serve-you)
127. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25686/can-being-funny-hurt-your-promotion-opportunities
128. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26866/what-are-the-most-necessary-non-language-specific-things-a-programmer-needs-to-k
129. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/what-kind-of-positions-could-a-beginning-developer-expect-to-qualify-for-in-five
130. [Do employers prefer software engineering over CS majors?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33911/do-employers-prefer-software-engineering-over-cs-majors)
131. [What subject do you discuss with your manager during a one-on-one?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34012/what-subject-do-you-discuss-with-your-manager-during-a-one-on-one)
132. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/should-i-start-making-connections-even-if-im-not-ready-for-a-job-yet
133. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36909/how-do-you-stop-yourself-from-programming
134. [What skills in game development are common in other software development areas?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/if-not-gamedev-what-do-i-do)
135. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37467/the-msc-gray-zone-how-to-deal-with-the-too-unexperienced-on-engineering-too-un
136. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/how-to-look-for-a-programming-job-out-of-your-area
137. [Does being a Senior Developer using one language qualify you to be a Senior Developer using another language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38393/does-being-a-senior-developer-using-one-language-qualify-you-to-be-a-senior-deve)
138. [Where do you go to read good examples of source code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38874/where-do-you-go-to-read-good-examples-of-source-code)
139. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39128/dealing-with-presidents-ceo-etc
140. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39620/looking-to-dig-deeper-in-programming
141. [Is "as long as it works" the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43188/is-as-long-as-it-works-the-norm)
142. [What is the motivation that makes you to stick with current job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44666/what-is-the-motivation-that-makes-you-to-stick-with-current-job)
143. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44671/how-should-a-programmer-decide-whether-to-get-an-mba-vs-continuing-as-a-programm
144. [Is programming as a profession in a race to the bottom?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45150/is-programming-as-a-profession-in-a-race-to-the-bottom)
145. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45404/do-i-deserve-a-promotion-higher-salary
146. [Tips for a first year CS student looking for a summer internship to gain experience?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46685/tips-for-a-first-year-cs-student-looking-for-a-summer-internship-to-gain-experie)
147. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50052/should-i-go-back-to-the-same-company
148. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48329/is-it-reasonable-to-expect-a-new-graduate-to-be-able-to-roll-his-own-blogging-so
149. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52791/web-developer-how-to-enhance-my-skillset
150. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52382/transitioning-from-chemical-engineering-to-software-industry-what-to-do
151. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53643/passive-income-for-a-programmer-teaching
152. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52540/pros-and-cons-between-learning-to-program-on-windows-and-linux-and-macs
153. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/what-next-after-5-year-of-experince-as-asp-net-developer
154. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55168/what-to-do-when-blocked
155. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57043/does-moving-from-vb-net-to-c-on-the-job-increase-your-programming-skills
156. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/senior-software-developer
157. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57782/what-are-the-preconditions-to-get-an-experienced-developer-from-working-as-a-fre
158. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58233/will-taking-a-job-thats-web-and-database-related-limit-my-software-development
159. [Employer admits that its developers are underpaid and undervalued. Time to part ways?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58501/employer-admits-that-its-developers-are-underpaid-and-undervalued-time-to-part)
160. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58606/rapid-application-development-good-bad-or-ugly
161. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61079/hobbyist-programmers-and-resume
162. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61167/from-programmer-to-system-admin
163. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63613/what-does-a-trainee-developer-do-what-is-the-clear-role
164. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/more-job-responsibilities-yet-still-entry-level
165. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63662/how-do-you-find-a-good-company-that-fits-your-style
166. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62883/is-it-reasonable-for-qa-department-to-get-higher-average-salary-than-that-of-dev
167. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63724/are-places-like-teksystems-or-volt-worth-it-for-a-mid-to-senior-developer
168. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63378/switching-from-software-testing-to-development
169. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64098/getting-a-job-in-foreign-country-what-are-my-options
170. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64192/which-job-opportunity-is-better-the-one-with-the-most-learning-potential-or-the
171. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/pros-and-cons-of-low-level-vs-high-level-software-development-careers
172. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69577/should-the-job-title-match-whats-written-on-the-job-offer
173. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70646/is-it-true-that-software-developers-role-is-short-term
174. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71032/would-you-accept-a-job-with-a-wrong-infrastructure
175. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71578/why-is-my-work-history-being-held-against-me
176. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72033/is-it-okay-to-put-all-your-spare-time-projects-under-an-umbrella-name-that-is-no
177. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/how-to-handle-arrogant-managers
178. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73787/how-do-you-know-you-have-what-it-takes-to-be-a-professional-programmer
179. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74611/how-to-present-self-taught-knowledge
180. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79745/from-an-outsider-how-where-to-enter-the-sw-development-field
181. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78928/working-as-a-programmer-for-gas-and-oil
182. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79011/industry-switch-to-space-technologies
183. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80853/tips-for-getting-a-job-with-international-relocation
184. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82383/adjusting-to-a-new-software-firm
185. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83411/returning-to-programming-math-after-a-years-long-inactivity-becoming-a-better-p
186. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82894/is-it-possible-to-do-internship-after-3-years-of-working-experience
187. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/885/is-it-worth-it-for-programmers-to-go-to-graduate-school
188. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/non-compete-agreements-when-are-they-reasonable-and-how-encompassing-should-th
189. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7495/how-important-is-a-big-name-school-for-fresh-grads
190. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/what-are-the-vital-qualities-need-for-a-junior-level-programmer-to-become-a-good
191. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11032/in-what-ways-stress-management-is-effectively-handled-by-the-good-software-peopl
192. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12879/do-programmers-grow-out-of-such-things-as
193. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/are-small-in-house-dev-teams-extinct
194. [Best approach to learning web programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15286/best-approach-to-learning-web-programming)
195. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13571/how-do-you-determine-the-fair-wage-to-pay-a-developer
196. [Learning embedded systems development without supervision](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14069/learning-embedded-systems-development-without-supervision)
197. [What do you do if you've had a series of bad employers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/what-do-you-do-if-youve-had-a-series-of-bad-employers)
198. [Hiring at start-ups vs established companies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/hiring-at-start-ups-vs-established-companies)
199. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16373/business-process-optimization
200. [What are some known/common development specialties?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17444/what-are-some-known-common-development-specialties)
201. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17068/do-you-have-a-panic-room
202. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/starting-as-a-developer-what-are-the-possible-career-steps
203. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/career-advice-needed-startups-clients-making-moves-the-whole-ball-of-wax
204. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19031/written-communication-skills-courses-how-important-are-they-for-developers
205. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/do-you-know-of-a-person-that-found-a-job-in-this-industry-without-an-education
206. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20653/is-it-better-to-specialize-in-a-single-field-i-like-or-expand-into-other-fields
207. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/java-vs-c-what-should-a-junior-programmer-just-finished-degree-consider-when
208. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/functional-programming-does-knowing-it-help-job-prospects
209. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21398/can-i-contribute-to-a-startup-besides-my-daily-job
210. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22498/using-stackoverflow-reputation-for-college-applications
211. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22055/mid-career-job-change-any-suggestions
212. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/masters-program-theory-track-vs-artifical-intelligence-track
213. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22412/working-with-fubar-refuctored-code
214. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23270/should-a-programmer-know-linux
215. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23848/being-a-good-mentee-a-protege
216. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/how-to-find-entry-level-positions-in-a-new-city
217. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27161/moving-beyond-business-logic-or-am-i-a-programmer-or-a-computer-scientist
218. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27757/how-do-you-sell-the-idea-of-sending-developers-to-user-conferences
219. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29601/first-90-days-of-a-new-hire-searching-for-blog-post
220. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/does-it-make-sense-to-focus-career-around-mainframes
221. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31530/obtaining-embedded-linux-experience
222. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/computer-security-and-c
223. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33436/how-to-decide-if-i-should-take-a-profit-sharing-offer-or-insist-on-hard-cash
224. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34805/what-to-do-if-youre-burnt-out
225. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34084/what-strategies-you-followed-to-keep-your-programming-skills-fresh-during-a-long
226. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/been-doing-net-for-several-years-and-am-thinking-about-a-platform-change-where
227. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35561/a-good-course-on-html-css-js-ux-worth-it-in-part-time
228. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35731/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-get-a-masters-and-bachelors-degree-from-the-same-universit
229. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36288/is-there-such-a-thing-as-too-much-experience
230. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37051/looking-for-jobs-after-a-project-ending-badly
231. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38178/what-are-the-best-rural-career-opportunities-for-a-programmer
232. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39262/what-are-good-personality-types-for-programming
233. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38661/is-it-fair-to-use-shortened-url-to-mention-and-give-links-of-live-projects-in-my
234. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40431/finding-time-to-use-stack-overflow
235. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40644/how-similar-are-programming-and-architecture
236. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41855/what-approaches-can-i-take-to-lower-the-odds-of-introducing-new-bugs-in-a-comple
237. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41898/when-does-a-programmer-know-when-a-new-job-is-not-right
238. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43959/is-client-side-html5-javascript-too-lame-after-youve-worked-on-server-side-c
239. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43133/programming-as-a-minor
240. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43482/software-development-company-business-plan
241. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/qa-engineer-road-ahead
242. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46167/how-to-deal-with-learning-a-new-platform-that-is-not-free
243. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46203/rule-of-thumb-to-estimate-cost-of-a-website
244. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47033/transitioning-from-internal-to-public-speaking
245. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49012/what-are-the-best-microsoft-certifications-to-start-with
246. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47477/why-do-employers-care-so-much-about-gpa
247. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50311/does-it-really-takes-5-10-years-or-more-to-be-really-good-in-programming
248. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/advice-for-how-to-handle-company-pride
249. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51546/how-do-you-handle-developer-that-has-taken-an-early-retirement
250. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53123/how-important-is-studying-algorithms-and-theory-is-to-becoming-a-great-programme

Apparently we hit the character limit, [closure candidates continue in another answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3206/25936). Please don't add anything to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Closure candidates #2**

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53692/i-need-some-career-guidance-please
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52657/what-would-you-recommend-to-someone-looking-to-work-with-java
3. [How to capitalize maximally on location-independence … my personal #1-incentive for working as a developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54612/how-to-capitalize-maximally-on-location-independence-my-personal-1-incentive)
4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56557/advancing-my-embedded-knowledge-with-a-cs-degree
5. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/what-should-i-quote-for-a-project-i-hope-to-get-a-job-at-the-end-of
6. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56941/are-highly-capable-programmers-paid-more-than-their-managers
7. [Open-Source, Consensus-Based Development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/open-source-consensus-based-development)
8. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/do-you-slowdown-after-you-decide-to-quit
9. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58956/will-a-programming-professional-certificate-from-a-university-enhance-my-resume
10. [Should I use design patterns or an algorithm? And what's the difference?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60157/will-design-patterns-help-me-in-this-case)
11. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60760/how-do-you-calculate-the-overhead-of-an-employee-in-a-software-consulting-firm
12. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/how-to-resolve-a-between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place-situation
13. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63589/finding-this-kind-of-companies-to-apply-to
14. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65607/volunteering-with-a-non-profit-to-expand-skills
15. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64936/how-can-i-make-myself-better-at-programming-working-at-a-shi-job
16. [As a professional .NET developer, should you learn to work with MSIL using reflection?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65250/as-a-professional-net-developer-should-you-learn-to-work-with-msil-using-refle)
17. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66297/im-a-professional-software-engineer-how-can-i-take-it-to-the-next-level
18. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66274/10-years-out-of-programming-wanting-to-return-how-to-best-approach-it
19. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/experienced-programmer-taking-classes-at-community-college-useful-or-too-basi
20. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67060/im-applying-for-a-position-at-a-startup-to-whom-should-i-address-my-cover-lett
21. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69918/how-do-i-increase-my-chances-of-getting-a-job-after-being-out-of-work-for-a-long
22. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69295/does-aiming-at-non-glamorous-positions-improve-chances-of-being-hired
23. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71304/is-creating-automated-tests-a-good-way-to-begin-a-career-as-a-programmer
24. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70471/where-am-i-as-a-programmer
25. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71580/why-there-are-no-real-software-companies-in-europe
26. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71096/msc-worth-going-back-for
27. [How many skills should I list on my resume, CV?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72040/how-many-skills-should-i-list-on-my-resume-cv)
28. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74021/reacting-to-question-will-you-act-as-an-on-call-consultant-after-you-leave
29. [Is it legal for me to contribute to open source software while employed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74105/is-it-legal-for-me-to-contribute-to-open-source-software-while-employed)
30. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74970/how-do-i-use-programming-experience-at-a-non-programming-position-on-my-resume-f
31. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75639/what-is-the-value-of-consulting-for-your-career
32. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75647/which-is-a-better-degree-a-computer-science-degree-or-an-it-degree
33. [Anyone Been Through the .NET Program with SetFocus?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76245/anyone-been-through-the-net-program-with-setfocus)
34. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76467/how-to-interpret-programmer-salary-survey-data-especially-concerning-different
35. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77564/essential-java-skills-for-future-career-advancement
36. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77938/developer-defecting-to-the-client-side
37. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77992/searching-for-job-openings-beyond-those-that-just-specific-programming-language
38. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/ive-got-my-masters-in-software-engineering-now-what
39. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77820/how-can-i-make-the-transition-from-being-a-beginner-to-an-intermediate-advanced
40. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/how-to-build-a-career-path-to-be-an-architect
41. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80410/what-is-expected-out-of-an-intern-know-everything
42. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80482/ways-for-self-taught-coder-to-build-a-portfolio-with-the-purpose-of-landing-an-e
43. [To be strict or pragmatic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84841/to-be-strict-or-pragmatic)
44. [Making the move to team leading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/making-the-move-to-team-leading)
45. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84909/jobs-that-use-programming-which-arent-in-the-technology-sector
46. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86042/switching-domains-in-ones-career
47. [Why are more programmers not freelance these days?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/why-are-more-programmers-not-freelance-these-days)
48. [What should I do to be language-agnostic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/what-should-i-do-to-be-language-agnostic)
49. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2563/does-it-pay-to-be-an-outstanding-software-developer
50. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/do-all-most-programmers-aspire-to-become-an-architect
51. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/any-advice-from-self-taught-programmers-on-competing-with-more-conventional-type
52. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9218/net-engineers-at-google-amazon-com-etc
53. [How do I improve my coding skills?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8721/how-do-i-improve-my-coding-skills)
54. [Can someone find a job as a programmer without an education?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8886/can-someone-find-a-job-as-a-programmer-without-an-education)
55. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/recommendations-for-learning-microsoft-azure
56. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/when-does-a-scripter-become-a-programmer
57. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/algorithm-development-in-jobs
58. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/where-to-get-experience-with-big-data
59. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15107/after-having-2-years-experience-in-software-testing-is-it-worth-taking-the-risk
60. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-go-to-college-or-focus-on-open-source-projects
61. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16289/career-stability-or-tech-skill-growth
62. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18920/why-is-having-your-developers-participating-in-online-communities-like-stackover
63. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18072/economics-of-a-career-in-bioinformatics
64. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17326/do-the-best-developers-look-for-a-better-job-or-a-better-job-finds-them
65. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18578/pmp-certificate-how-did-you-achieve-it-how-was-the-preparation
66. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/best-way-to-find-part-time-programming-work-while-at-uni
67. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/can-passionate-programmers-with-limited-abilities-have-life-outside-work
68. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/how-to-get-people-involved-in-your-project
69. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/how-many-blogs-do-you-follow-regularly-and-how-many-are-enough
70. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/engineering-support-to-development-career-switch
71. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19750/how-to-get-back-to-software-engineering-after-a-break
72. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/typing-skills-do-developers-need-a-formal-training
73. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21639/how-to-get-a-programmer-job-with-it-experience-after-doing-a-masters-in-cs
74. [Motivation for programming in a specific language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/motivation-for-programming-in-a-specific-language)
75. [How do you get into the zone? How long does it take? What steps do you take before?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20542/how-do-you-get-into-the-zone-how-long-does-it-take-what-steps-do-you-take-befo)
76. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/what-non-technical-skills-do-i-need
77. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/is-it-more-important-to-focus-on-a-business-domain-or-a-programming-stack-techno
78. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23077/is-it-considered-easy
79. [How many programming languages is a programmer expected to be an expert at?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/how-many-programming-languages-is-a-programmer-expected-to-be-an-expert-at)
80. [How Do You Determine Your Hourly Rate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23453/how-do-you-determine-your-hourly-rate)
81. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/whom-do-you-think-of-as-your-guru-for-your-development-career-and-what-you-have
82. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/what-do-you-do-when-youre-de-motivated-and-appreciation-and-recognition-are-gi
83. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/working-remotely-as-a-career-objective
84. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/what-should-a-contractors-mandate-be
85. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24847/tips-for-developers-moving-from-local-applications-development-to-web-programmin
86. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/how-do-you-get-a-high-paying-job-programming-in-finance
87. [What are the skills you look for when hiring a fresher/newbie for developement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26191/what-are-the-skills-you-look-for-when-hiring-a-fresher-newbie-for-developement)
88. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27089/switch-to-a-java-job-but-with-no-real-professional-background-how
89. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/how-important-is-blogging-tutorial-generation-to-career-development
90. [What is meant by XML/XSLT/XPath and asynchronous programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/what-is-meant-by-xml-xslt-xpath-and-asynchoronous-programming)
91. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28588/what-is-a-programmers-unique-selling-proposition
92. [Abstraction: The War between solving the problem and a general solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32964/abstraction-the-war-between-solving-the-problem-and-a-general-solution)
93. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/will-accepting-low-end-first-software-job-hurt-my-chances-at-a-dream-job-later
94. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33892/suggestions-on-switching-from-lamp-based-web-design-development-to-game-design-d
95. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33397/resources-for-entry-level-software-engineering-positions
96. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35068/things-which-should-be-know-or-learned-with-winforms
97. [Do I need to go to a big-name university?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/do-i-need-to-go-to-a-big-name-university)
98. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33986/software-consultancy-or-in-house-development
99. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/how-should-i-take-being-told-that-i-was-wrong
100. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35281/a-typical-day-of-a-programmer-in-a-consultancy-vs-a-product-company
101. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-stressful-can-a-paid-side-project-be
102. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34039/preparing-to-move-countries
103. [If most of team can't follow the architecture, what do you do?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/if-most-of-team-cant-follow-the-architecture-what-do-you-do)
104. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34311/what-if-youve-been-asked-to-develop-a-site-and-the-client-later-introduces-tsc
105. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35765/what-do-you-need-to-know-before-applying-for-a-job
106. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36840/listing-my-programming-experience-on-my-resume
107. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-important-is-presentation-technique-for-your-career
108. [As a self-taught programmer, how do I get the academic foundation without attending school again?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37307/as-a-self-taught-programmer-how-do-i-get-the-academic-foundation-without-attend)
109. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/are-these-company-terms-good-for-a-programmer-or-should-i-move
110. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37027/how-has-being-in-an-it-related-professional-society-helped-you
111. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36654/what-does-your-university-1st-class-mean
112. [Best industry to work for as a developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37532/best-industry-to-work-for-as-a-developer)
113. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37052/finding-telecommuting-opportunities-as-a-recent-college-graduate
114. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37126/career-progression-from-systems-architect
115. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/finding-internship-opportunities
116. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/is-a-masters-worth-it
117. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37941/would-you-recommend-incorporation-to-a-programmer-which-works-exclusively-as-a-c
118. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37954/how-do-you-determine-which-skills-are-marketable
119. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38127/customized-computer-science-degree-what-other-field-would-mesh-well-with-compu
120. [What to do when coding begins to feel boring, like it is all just more of the same?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38225/what-to-do-when-coding-begins-to-feel-boring-like-it-is-all-just-more-of-the-sa)
121. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38927/is-there-a-job-for-develop-c-libraries
122. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39008/what-are-some-well-respected-programmers-magazines-both-online-and-print
123. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38617/is-it-still-relevant-to-learn-c-these-days
124. [Learning C# and stuck in a rut](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/learning-c-and-stuck-in-a-rut)
125. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40455/tips-for-a-developer-moving-from-net-to-mainframe
126. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40052/what-resources-are-available-to-support-programmers-who-wish-to-work-internation
127. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40547/do-any-universities-offer-advanced-non-programming-specific-degrees-aimed-spe
128. [How should I evaluate a training class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39509/how-should-i-evaluate-a-training-class)
129. [Compiler Jobs - How Much Education Is Needed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40202/compiler-jobs-how-much-education-is-needed)
130. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/net-starter-developer-portfolio
131. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42030/does-learning-to-develop-for-ios-create-a-lock-in
132. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42779/how-long-does-it-take-to-pass-the-java-programmer-certification
133. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/how-much-does-it-cost-to-develop-an-android-application
134. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42186/fresh-graduates-what-are-employers-looking-for
135. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42839/online-programming-degree-that-employers-will-not-disregard
136. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/transitioning-from-a-mechanical-engineer-to-software-developer-what-path-to-tak
137. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/what-to-do-if-i-am-working-on-a-language-that-i-dont-like
138. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43158/vb-net-developer-for-6-years-am-i-stuck
139. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44634/too-much-to-learn-so-little-time
140. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44751/published-windows-phone-7-apps-good-for-the-resume-cv
141. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44973/should-i-worry-about-a-companys-reputation-before-joining-it
142. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/going-into-web-development-without-a-c-s-degree-suggestions
143. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47044/web-application-development-over-c-development
144. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/youve-been-working-on-a-platform-for-as-long-as-you-remember-not-anymore-how
145. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46675/what-is-the-most-professional-way-to-deal-with-another-programmer-who-has-checke
146. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47684/do-developers-ever-contract-by-retainer-if-not-why
147. [Mock Objects for Testing - Test Automation Engineer Perspective](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47331/mock-objects-for-testing-test-automation-engineer-perspective)
148. [How to explain my 5 burnt-out years off to a new employer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47979/how-to-explain-my-5-burnt-out-years-off-to-a-new-employer)
149. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49490/somewhere-to-get-inspiration-pair-up-the-creative-with-the-tech
150. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50089/how-do-i-convince-my-boss-to-come-here-and-see-how-good-companies-are-doing
151. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/importance-of-a-1st-class-degree
152. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49310/for-those-of-you-who-are-senior-developers-what-do-you-look-for-in-a-new-company
153. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50688/does-the-type-of-prior-employers-matter-when-applying-for-a-new-job
154. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50585/computer-science-degrees-and-real-world-experience
155. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/in-transitioning-to-c-from-java-how-can-i-ensure-that-i-am-not-only-proficient
156. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51758/what-do-dbas-do
157. [Should I keep investing into data structures and algorithms?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50755/should-i-keep-investing-into-data-structures-and-algorithms)
158. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52005/im-tempted-to-include-easter-eggs-in-my-code-will-this-get-me-fired
159. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54065/what-should-i-know-before-starting-my-first-consulting-project
160. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56642/skills-to-focus-on-to-land-big-5-software-engineer-position
161. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57257/bad-style-programming-am-i-pretending-too-much
162. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55025/i-keep-looping-learning-and-forget-and-then-learning-something-new-and-forget
163. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57358/oracle-certification
164. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57480/how-to-penetrate-the-qa-industry-after-layoffs-next-steps
165. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/after-j2se-should-i-learn-j2ee-or-c
166. [High level vs. low level programming. Do I really have to choose?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/high-level-vs-low-level-programming-do-i-really-have-to-choose)
167. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56454/how-to-get-a-job-in-robotics
168. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58995/research-useful-for-getting-a-job
169. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61924/do-you-know-of-any-virtual-online-internships-for-programming-or-software-develo
170. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62015/career-strategy-for-those-of-us-who-like-re-inventing-wheels
171. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62090/what-is-a-good-industry-for-doing-new-front-end-web-development
172. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62113/c-developer-losing-direction
173. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62381/what-strategy-to-landing-an-enterprise-postion-given-a-non-enterprisey-past
174. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62522/understanding-programming-and-self-improvement-sources-about-the-real-logic
175. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62585/having-experience-vs-not-before-masters
176. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62662/does-anyone-work-in-know-much-about-programming-jobs-for-scientific-medical
177. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63744/does-being-a-linux-only-expert-limit-career-choices-outside-academia
178. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63302/knowing-a-language-but-not-the-ide
179. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63349/mediocre-programmer-wants-to-work-at-a-google-like-company-where-to-start
180. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64909/how-much-have-you-learned-at-school-vs-on-the-job
181. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65666/i-dont-still-figure-out-what-i-would-do-internship
182. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64983/how-well-should-a-fresh-graduate-know-a-language
183. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65792/is-it-immoral-to-buy-off-topic-development-books-on-the-companies-dime
184. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63447/difference-in-the-general-nature-of-work-in-the-east-and-the-west
185. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67621/open-source-as-a-job
186. [Pure vs Applied Math For Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69970/pure-vs-applied-math-for-programmers)
187. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71237/career-choices-for-a-programmer
188. [what counts as "experience" with a particular language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68790/what-counts-as-experience-with-a-particular-language)
189. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70515/amount-of-open-source-software-in-proprietary-corporate-software
190. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71568/how-to-become-an-excellent-applications-programmer-coming-from-low-level-backgr
191. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73350/what-route-to-take-to-become-a-systems-developer
192. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74162/how-big-are-the-different-programming-worlds
193. [When applying for an entry level programming position, how do I include my coding examples?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75348/when-applying-for-an-entry-level-programming-position-how-do-i-include-my-codin)
194. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75587/should-i-avoid-html-css-projects-now-that-i-am-proficient-with-real-programmin
195. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74406/how-long-would-you-offer-to-train-a-replacement-if-you-chose-to-change-jobs-and
196. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75065/i-want-to-get-a-job-in-bio-related-programming-what-should-i-do-next
197. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77287/how-common-is-partial-telecommuting-for-programming-jobs-also-is-this-what-is-m
198. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76339/confused-about-career-options-in-web-developement
199. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75096/what-can-i-expect-when-moving-from-university-to-a-real-programming-job
200. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77678/is-it-better-to-focus-on-one-database-architecture-or-learn-them-all
201. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76659/how-is-a-software-developer-different-from-a-software-consultant-what-makes
202. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78058/what-programming-languages-are-required-for-a-career-in-network-security
203. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78406/writing-better-timesheet
204. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79134/what-are-the-three-most-important-questions-you-should-ask-your-team-about-your
205. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80792/what-modes-of-profit-are-open-to-programmers
206. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80045/becoming-a-professional-programmer-without-going-to-college
207. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81135/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-net-developer-curriculum
208. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81183/would-it-be-harmful-to-have-a-company-that-frequently-has-security-blunders-on-y
209. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/2nd-career-option-as-a-programmer-creator
210. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83175/how-can-i-actually-apply-the-javascript-i-am-learning
211. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83885/learning-to-manage-time-when-making-the-move-to-team-leading
212. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86392/switch-from-back-end-to-front-end-programming-im-out-of-my-comfort-zone-shoul
213. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86922/what-type-of-career-path-jobs-for-a-developer-to-have-best-work-life-balance
214. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87098/how-to-quantify-product-work-in-resume
215. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28732/to-be-a-software-developer-do-you-have-to-be-smart
216. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58250/what-percentage-should-a-consulting-company-take-off-the-top-of-your-pay
217. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82502/how-to-start-learning-j2ee-especially-jpa
218. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/whats-it-like-to-be-a-developer-working-on-trading-systems
219. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/java-or-c-for-university-cs-courses
220. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27173/does-graduating-a-term-later-as-a-cs-student-matter
221. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28317/when-is-it-ok-to-flex-your-skill
222. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28693/role-of-microsoft-certifications-ado-net-asp-net-wpf-wcf-and-career
223. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42755/applying-to-a-company-while-personally-working-on-a-comparable-project
224. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44692/have-you-tried-to-switch-to-different-kind-of-language-and-find-a-job-in-a-new
225. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55555/how-can-i-transition-from-being-a-9-5er-to-being-self-employed
226. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/anyone-been-successful-changing-their-career-without-having-to-start-over-from-s
227. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66669/how-to-tackle-an-experienced-c-programmer
228. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/career-change-after-years-as-a-programmer
229. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72164/junior-programmer-working-with-a-poor-senior-programmer-and-poor-code
230. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82920/looking-for-unpaid-interns-2-am-i-crazy

---

1. Add questions here

Comment: I've went through **all** open stci-career questions... 90% of the above are career advice (off topic) and the rest are mostly not constructive... Please review.

Comment: Lot of sweat and hard work.

Comment: BTW: when is the plan for deletion to begin?

Comment: @DipanMehta Questions identified as delete candidates will be deleted asap, if not salvaged on Wed 7. Same process for merge and closure candidates, they will be merged and closed, however there will be some time before deletion. Not much though, as the point of the tag cleanup was to salvage them within the two week period. If they had no activity within that period they might be deleted as soon as they are closed.