# Closed questions: What is wrong?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Career Development Questions - Moving rather than closing?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/career-development-questions-moving-rather-than-closing)

As I write this post, out of 48 questions on the main page, there are are 27 that are closed.  Is the FAQ is not clear?  Are closing votes too generous?  Is it a blip?  ...

Answer (score 2):

Questions are being closed and edited with respect to the [Structured Tag Clean-Up Initiative for the careers tag](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/structured-tag-cleanup-career). It should subside soon, although the frequency of edits might be a bit too high this time around.