# Will this edit to “Burned out on programming and given up?” make it on-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, stci

The question [Burned out on programming and given up?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11425/1130) is currently [flagged for deletion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3172/1130).

Would it be considered on-topic if the personal wall-of-text... er.. information was removed, and it is turned into a question about how to get past programming burnout, which seems to be what the OP was asking in the first place?

**Edit**

I have heavily edited the question in an attempt to bring it back on-topic. Please let me know if you think of anything else I can do to it.

Comment: Closed this question as it refers to the [career structure cleanup](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/structured-tag-cleanup-career) that is now over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not looking for an on topic version of this question, but for a constructive version. How to survive a burnout is essentially asking for war stories, and that doesn't really fit the Q&A format.

The only way I see salvaging the question would be to make it about preventing burn out, but that would make it an exact duplicate of [Active steps to prevent a burn-out?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56677/active-steps-to-prevent-a-burn-out), which is obviously *not* what the OP intended.

---

Good edit. Obsolete comments removed, as was the single "not an answer" answer... Noise reduced, although I still don't see the question as salvageable.

---

The question is now deleted as the only attention that the question received (other than your edit) was a delete vote.

Comment: I don't think so.... one is asking how to prevent burnout and another is asking how to survive it. The answers are widely different. One suggests small things to focus on something other than programming regularly, and the other suggests taking a vacation from coding completely.

Comment: @Rachel Hmmm, you are right, I revised the answer to explain my reasoning... What I meant was that the only way to salvage it (imho) would be to actually make it about preventing burnout...

Comment: I agree with this. Upon further thought the question was off-topic for the site.